# How to get Waypoints information from Pixhawk and send it to Raspberry while the mission is uploaded through mission planner?

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, dronekit-python, dronekit, mavlink

I am working on a project using a fixed wings UAV.

I want to perform RC override when UAV reaches certain waypoints.

I have defined the waypoints and uploaded the mission to Pixhawk using Misison Planner

I have a 4G module connected to Raspberry Pi and then to Pixhawk through USB to establish a UDP connection with Mission Planner

Is there a way to know if I reached the 2nd waypoint for example from Raspberry Pi using Python DroneKit without having my waypoints defined in the script on the Pi?

If any one have any idea about how to do this or if it is not possible to do so?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code here.

http://python.dronekit.io/examples/mission_import_export.html

The code is simple. I hope you will be able to do it.

You can get the distance to way point so you know the where you are heading now. you can download and parse the mission.